# Hibernate list and Set mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Just learning Hibernate.
In list type property mapping, It seems its required to write "list-index" while persisting the list. This contains the index/position of elements in the list.

Why this "list-index" is required? Is it for reconstruction of list while loading again from DB?

If this is the case, can't Hibernate just take the sequence of insertion as the basis for reconstruction instead of relying on this "list-index" ?

Further, In Set we don't have anything like "set-index" Is it because in a set position is not important? like in HashSet or TreeSet (sorted version) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is the case, can't Hibernate just take the sequence of insertion as the basis for reconstruction instead of relying on this "list-index" ?

The answer is no. Because in rows of database, inherently there is no sense of order. No one can guarantee you that you can get the result of the query, ordered as you inserted it in DB. So to keep track of the indices, Hibernate also need to keep index column.

But generation of HashSets and TreeSets do not depends on the order of the elements. If the hashing method and/or the compare method are known, then using them HashSets and/or TreeSets can be constructed from the set of elements only.